# Как переименовать столбец в таблице

Tags: c#, mysql

Пытался сделать так, но ничего не происходит ( не нашел решения в инете по этому вопросу.

```
MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Students CHANGE COLUMN `" + selectedd + "` `" + textBox1.Text + "`", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html). UPDATE изменяет данные, а не структуру.

Comment: пробывал и это тоже MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students CHANGE `" + selectedd + "` `" + textBox1.Text + "` TEXT", sqlConnection);

Comment: Показывать надо не код сборки запроса, а результат сборки. Т.е. текст запроса после всех подстановок и плюсований. Ибо хрен знает какая у Вас там в переменных дрянь завалялась...

Comment: Дело в том что мне ошибок не выдает, я заключал это в try и catch

Comment: Соберите текст запроса в отдельной переменной. И покажите результат.

Comment: Пробывал так один фиг не работает MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students CHANGE Предмет3 Предмет34 TEXT", sqlConnection);

Comment: @Akina этот как собрать то

Comment: 1) Кириллица в именах полей недопустима. Квотируйте как минимум. 2) Вот как-то так: `strSQL = "ALTER TABLE Students CHANGE " + selectedd + " " + textBox1.Text + " TEXT"`.

Comment: @Akina допустима ! я пробывал без переменных, напрямую Предмет3 на Предмет34

Comment: Запрос - рабочий. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=769acf08abf1e8e47f42e17776d9f009). Проблема не в нём. *допустима ! я пробывал без переменных, напрямую Предмет3 на Предмет34* Да не вопрос - пользуйся. И молись, что это в будущем не приведёт к проблемам.

Comment: @Akina ладно буду смотреть в чем там проблема то

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students CHANGE `" + selectedd + "` `" + textBox1.Text + "` TEXT", sqlConnection);
```